# Using the # symbol in equations

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to use the `#` symbol in Latex equations. 
I already tried `\#`, but it is not working: When the `#` symbol appears in an equation, then the rest becomes a `$` sign instead of `#`.

Here is my code:

```
({12#-3-4\div 5#3\%})
```

Comment: `\#` should be what you need

Comment: If \# isn't working, you must be loading other font package which is replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

In LaTeX `# $ % & ~ _ ^ \ { }` are treated as reserved characters. If we need to print these characters, we must add backslash before them. This works for

```
\#
\$
\%
\&
\_
\{
\}
```

(not for `^`, `~` and `\`).

For instance, `%` (percent symbol) is used to comment any content in a document or in a template. To print percent symbol we should type `\%`

For your problem the solution is to type `\#`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- since when does `\^` print *only* the circumflex?  last time i looked, this was a text accent (and must be put *over* something), and triggered an error in math.

Comment: sorry meant to say `#` and `%`  I point but it doesn't work for `^` later in same line:-)  I'll delete and re-add

Comment: This answer happens to work for `#` and `%` but is wrong for `\\ `, `\^`, `\~`